failure error attempting to create a a new flow in Azure PromptFlow within Azure AI Studio
Go to Azure AI Studio,
open prompt flow,
CREATE new flow...
Choose from gallery/templates...
Fails (multiple users)
Used to work a week ago, and still works in another AI Studio instance I have.   User Rights/Roles should be similar or exact in both cases.
My 3rd Azure Prompt Flow within another ML Workspace also works perfectly.   only under this particular AI Studio instance (and it's ML Workspace within the AI Hub)
Has anyone seen this error?   Looks like it can't access some ai.azure.com asset.
BadRequest
This request is not authorized to perform this operation.This request is not authorized to perform this operation.This request is not authorized to perform this operation.This request is not authorized to perform this operation.This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
Properties
Stack trace
Error: Request failed with status code 400
at cG (https://ai.azure.com/assets/index-3968d242.js:307:15808)
at uG (https://ai.azure.com/assets/index-3968d242.js:307:15996)
at XMLHttpRequest.y (https://ai.azure.com/assets/index-3968d242.js:308:1672)
Made sure resources have same permissions as in working instance.
Expect it to deploy a Flow from the selected template


BadRequest-This request is not authorized to perform this operation.This request is not authorized to perform this operation.This request is not authorized to perform this operation.This request is not authorized to perform this operation.This request is not authorized to perform this operation. Properties Stack trace Error: Request failed with status code 400 at cG

Use the Azure SDK or CLI to deploy the Flow from the template. Then you can be able to capture and handle any errors during the deployment process.
Code:
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.ai.ml.entities import PipelineJob
from azure.ai.ml.dsl import pipeline

# Authenticate and create a client
def authenticate():
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    subscription_id = "<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>"
    resource_group = "<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP>"
    workspace_name = "<YOUR_WORKSPACE_NAME>"
    ml_client = MLClient(credential, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
    return ml_client

# Verify template configuration
def verify_template_configuration(template):
    # Placeholder: Add actual template verification logic
    return True

# Validate resource access
def validate_resource_access(resources):
    # Placeholder: Add actual resource access validation logic
    return True

# Deploy Flow using Azure SDK
def deploy_flow(ml_client, template, parameters):
    try:
        job = PipelineJob(
            display_name="example-pipeline",
            description="A sample pipeline job",
            jobs=template  # This should be a pipeline definition or component
        )
        ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(job)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Deployment failed: {e}")
        return False

# Check deployment logs
def check_deployment_logs(ml_client):
    # Placeholder: Retrieve and analyze deployment logs
    logs = ml_client.jobs.list()
    return logs

# Main function
def main():
    ml_client = authenticate()
    
    template = {
        # Example pipeline structure
        "job1": {
            "type": "command",
            "command": "echo Hello World",
            "environment": "AzureML-sklearn-0.24-ubuntu18.04-py37-cpu:1"
        }
    }
    parameters = {
        "param1": "value1",
        "param2": "value2"
    }
    resources = ["resource1", "resource2"]
    
    if verify_template_configuration(template):
        print("Template configuration is correct.")
    else:
        print("Template configuration issue detected.")
    
    if validate_resource_access(resources):
        print("Resource access is validated.")
    else:
        print("Resource access issue detected.")
    
    if deploy_flow(ml_client, template, parameters):
        print("Flow deployed successfully.")
    else:
        print("Flow deployment issue detected.")
    
    logs = check_deployment_logs(ml_client)
    print(f"Deployment logs: {logs}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Use PipelineJob from the Azure SDK to define and deploy the Flow, making the process more specific and capturing detailed errors.

The authenticate function uses DefaultAzureCredential and initializes MLClient with the subscription ID, resource group, and workspace name
Reference:

Run flows in Azure ML pipeline)

Prompt flow in Azure AI Studio



Thanks Suresh, we'll take a look.
is the prompt flow deploy being handled from the AI Project or the AI Hub resource?  (so can recheck permissions).
Odd thing is, this works fine on another AI Studio instance we have, which should have identical setup.    And in this problem instance, it worked a few months ago, then started failing (haven't found what if anything changed).

Deployment of Prompt Flow in Azure AI Studio involves permissions in both the AI Project and the AI Hub. To identify and resolve the issue it is important to understand which resource's permissions are affecting the deployment process. Permissions on the AI Hub determine the ability to access shared resources and templates. AI Hub acts as a central repository for sharing and managing AI assets across different projects and workspaces.
